# Data parsing from mysql into highchart with json

Tags: php, mysql, json, highcharts

new to this and (nearly) desperated. What i want to do is the following:

- read temp from sensor (works, returns float)
- save data in mysql database boxklima.sensorid (works - table is boxklima.0414604605ff) in sets of date-temp pairs the date is stored as 2014-01-01 09:00:00 (datetime) and the temp as 12.123 (real)
- graph data as x-axis: date y-axis: temp (totally messed this up)

So i stick to highcharts which looks nice and seems be easy to set up because everything happens client-side (except data-parsing).

Now I dont't know exactly how do create the array which is given to highchart. It should look something like this (content of **create-graph.html**)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script‌​>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'spline'
        },
        series: [{}]
    };

    $.getJSON('data.php', function(data) {
        options.series[0].data = temp;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });

});
</script>
```

Parse the data with the **data.php** (content shown below) from the sql-server, should generate the data on call, right?

```
<php>
 $dbc = mysqli_connect("localhost", "pi", "pi", "boxklima");
 $query = "SELECT date,temp FROM 0414604605ff";
 $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
 $i=0;
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
    $rows[$i]=array($row['date'],$row['temp']);
    $i++;
 }
 echo json_encode($rows);
</php>
```

Opening (in browser) of data.php just shows

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect("localhost", "pi", "pi", "boxklima"); $query = "SELECT date,temp FROM 0414604605ff"; $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query); $i=0; while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) { $rows[$i]=array($row['date'],$row['temp']); $i++; } echo json_encode($rows);
```

Opening create-graph.html results in empty screen. 
Credentials set to 755, the php-file has execution bit set, to. Files are in the same directory.

Help appreciated, thank you in advance, i'am lost in information and definitly puzzled.
Read through the other topics but since I'am new to this it gives me only little chunks which I was not able to match together. :S
Further information:

```
lighttpd/1.4.31

PHP Version 5.4.36-0+deb7u1
additional config files parsed

/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-gd.ini, 
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-mysql.ini, 
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini 

json support    enabled
json version    1.2.1 

mysql Client API version    5.5.40
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your php file to this:

```
<?php
  $dbc = mysqli_connect("localhost", "pi", "pi", "boxklima");
  $query = "SELECT date,temp FROM 0414604605ff";
  $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
  $i=0;
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
     $rows[$i]=array($row['date'],$row['temp']);
     $i++;
  }
  echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

In create-graph.html, 'temp' variable is undefined.(You may open JavaScript Console and check for JavaScript errors)This is the reason why that page is blank.

Looking at your data.php file, I think the 'data' variable in callback function of $.getJSON would have structure like following:

```
[
   [2014-01-01 09:00:00, 12.43]
   [2014-01-02 09:00:00, 13.57]
]
```

Basically Array of Arrays.
So changing your function to this might help:

```
$.getJSON('data.php', function(data) {
    dataTemp = [];
    for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        dataTemp.push(data[i][1]);  // '1' index for getting that temp value. '0' for date.     
    }
    options.series[0].data = dataTemp;
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

Also Please post the contents of data.php when you open it in web browser.
Also mention the JavaScript Console Error(if you get) when you open create-graph.html after making the changes.

Comment: thought that the temp-variable would refer to the temp column in the database - changed the code as you mentioned - no result.

Comment: No temp is undefined. Can you post the output of your data.php file when you open in browser? and also can you open the javascript console and check for errors and tell me? Use Ctrl+Shift+j in Google Chrome.

Comment: $dbc = mysqli_connect("localhost", "pi", "pi", "boxklima"); $query = "SELECT date,temp FROM 0414604605ff"; $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query); $i=0; while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) { $rows[$i]=array($row['date'],$row['temp']); $i++; } echo json_encode($rows);

Comment: looking for the console, may take a few minutes to fins it :D

Comment: Hey Listen, You are using the wrong php tags. See the Edit of my answer and change your php file first. Syntax when you start writing php code is <?php  // your code.  ?>

Comment: NS_ERROR_XPC_SECURITY_MANAGER_VETO:  unity-global-property-initializer.js:238


Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead jquery.min.js:1
ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined exporting.js:23


Die Zeichenkodierung des HTML-Dokuments wurde nicht deklariert. Das Dokument wird in manchen Browser-Konfigurationen mit verstümmeltem Text dargestellt, wenn das Dokument Zeichen außerhalb des US-ASCII-Bereichs enthält. Die Zeichenkodierung der Seite muss im Dokument oder Transferprotokoll deklariert werden.

Type Error: data is null

Comment: I will appreciate If you kindly learn basics of PHP, JavaScript and jQuery, else you will be committing very small mistakes and will spend hours fixing them.

Comment: Let me figure out that null response from the php file

Comment: See the last line. data is null because your php code is not outputting the correct data which you want from your database. It is rather outputting the code you wrote as you don't used php tags properly. Tell me output after changing those php tags.

Comment: null, checked the SQL query which is okay in phpmyadmin

Comment: Check whether your connection to database is OK or not by printing the variables $data and $dbc. Debug your php first and then edit your JavaScript accordingly.

Comment: checked db connection which failed because of sql-errors...
fixed that, php returns now:
[["2015-01-14 21:28:55","23.687"],["2015-01-14 21:29:07","23.687"],["2015-01-14 21:29:18","23.75"],["2015-01-14 21:29:32","23.75"]]

Comment: wondering about the "" around the temps, shouldn't they be floats, not strings? checking json_encode options

Comment: echo json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); fixed that, now data looks good

Comment: Don't worry about this. You may parse the float value out of this string in JavaScript.Just Google it. So Finally this output will be the value of that data variable in $.getJSON. Now form your dataTemp array accordingly and pass it to highcharts. You may use console.log(variable) to debug. This will output the data in JavaScript console.  I hope my answered helped :)

Comment: all of that - thank you a lot - would vote, but I'am not allowed yet :) THANK YOU *thumbs up

Comment: so I'am gonna clean this mess up and will pots the working code with nice documentation time by time --- got it working though.

Comment: Sounds good. you also need to set xAxis in highcharts as mentioned in Other Answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your string dates to timestamp and set datetime type of xAxis. To help, see [strtotime function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and apply in to your PHP script.